# Make Intent Filter only respond to external links

Tags: android

Not sure if this can be done, but I have an intent filter in my Android manifest that responds to a certain url:

```
    <data
            android:host="reddit.com"
            android:scheme="http"></data>

        <data
            android:host="reddit.com"
            android:scheme="https"></data>
```

This then launches an Activity which parses the url and launches the relevant activity based on the url.

This works great for when I click a link that matches the pattern outside of my app, but when I click on a similar link INSIDE of my app, I want just my custom `LinkMovementMethod` to handle it.

So my question is, is there a way for the intent filter to only respond to links outside of the app? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, is there a way for the intent filter to only respond to links outside of the app?

No.

You need to fix the way that you are creating links inside of your app, such that they do not attempt to launch an activity with an implicit `Intent` if the link matches your desired pattern, but instead handles the link inside your app.

Comment: That seems to be the logical thing to do. Thanks for your help.